# Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet error in compilation

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jsf-2

I'm using eclipse Indigo and Tomcat 6.0.3 and JSF 2.0.

I'm working from [this](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-internationalization-example/) example but I get these errors on runtime:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2818)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:1078)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4612)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1385)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1389)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1653)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1662)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1642)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

I have added all the `javaee-web-api`, `javax.faces-api` jars in maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
  <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.8.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax</groupId>
   <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
   <version>6.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is jar file problem. Show your maven dependency.

Comment: I have updated the maven dependencies above...

Answer (score 12):

My perception is right. This was jar file problem. You did not put right JSF jar file in your classpath.

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Replace above dependency with following dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.13</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Got the same error as Khirthan and indeed this fixed it, thanks! Also, how did you know that's the correct dependency? And why is this not listed higher at the Maven repository site? http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=jsf